# Python subprocess to get real output and load output to variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I have to get command output to variable in python.

I am using python subprocess

```
from subprocess import *
var1 = check_output(["some_command"])
```

Above Command successfully loads command output to variable var1

I want to see real time output on to the terminal. I can use call like below

```
 call(["some command"])
```

Now i want to achieve two things at same time that is, load output to variable and display output to terminal. Please help me.

Comment: You can perhaps print the output in `var1`, i.e. `print(var1)`

Comment: But real time does not happen right?

Comment: Perhaps you can stdout to a file then tail -f that file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting realtime output using subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803265/getting-realtime-output-using-subprocess)

Comment: That indeed does not happen realtime, only after the program has exited

Comment: just use this link `https://stackoverflow.com/a/75175057/12780274`  is very simple

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work, for line-based real-time output:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["some_command"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
var1 = []
while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    var1.append(line)
    sys.stdout.write(line)
var1 = "".join(var1)
```

The iterator version of `readline` (`for line in proc.stdout`) does not work here because it performs too much buffering.  You could also use `proc.stdout.read(1)` instead of `readline()` to completely disable buffering.

Note that this will not port well to Python 3 because `sys.stdout` is text-oriented (uses Unicode), but processes are byte-oriented (although the latter can be changed in recent Python 3 versions).

Comment: just use this link `https://stackoverflow.com/a/75175057/12780274`  is very simple