# Kill program run with exec(open(file).read()) in python

Tags: python, tkinter, exec, sys

In my code I am calling a pipeline from a tkinter gui. When the user presses the Run button the entire pipeline starts running. If certain settings are selected a toplevel of the main GUI is called which asks for an aditional file. This all works except when the cancel button or the close window X is pressed. The toplevel closes but the program keeps running. Eventually it will crash because the file is absent. calling sys.exit() isn't the solution because then the entire gui shuts down and I only want the specific toplevel to close and to stop the running file.

How do I kill a file running with exec(open(file).read()) without killing the entire program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Honestly, you probably shouldn't use `exec` at all, but assuming you do, `exec` is still running in the same process and thread as your main program, there's no exiting it without killing the main program.

You should open it in another process, subprocess or thread. Since your `exec` seem to be running python code, you could simply use:

```
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen(['python', filename'])
```

And then it runs in the background, your normal process continues, and you can kill it at any point with .

```
p.kill()
```

It gets more complicated than that if you want to give that process input or read out its output, but that's a matter for a different question. You can start here to see how to read the output: [Store output of subprocess.Popen call in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/store-output-of-subprocess-popen-call-in-a-string)

A small example to get the output would be something like this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(['python', filename], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, errors = p.communicate()
```

However this will wait until the process completes its run, so maybe start all that from another thread, or find another way to get the output (perhaps to a log file)

Notice I used just `'python'` in `Popen`, if the python executable is not in your path or has a different name, you should replace that with the full path to the executable

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but when using Popen no print statements come through. And I didn't write the pipeline I am trying to call which is written very poorly so I need all the print statements

Comment: Like I said in the answer, it's possible to get the printed output from `Popen`, you should read up on how, or ask a new question if you're having problems with it. Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/store-output-of-subprocess-popen-call-in-a-string

Comment: The pipeline should start creating images and files but when using Popen these do not appear? Does Popen store things like this untill the very end of its runtime somewhere or is there another problem? Running the entire pipeline takes a few hours so I haven't tried that yet

Comment: I've added in edit a small example of getting the output (and errors) from Popen (see above). I can't answer more than that in comments without seeing your code, like I said, that's a subject for a whole other question on the matter. The fact is that `exec` isn't killable without killing the program that started it.

Comment: Maybe this will help to get popen output live on stdout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062340/python-subprocess-output-to-stdout