# Subprocess does not store output in variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I am trying to capture the output of this command:

```
ls -l /sys/class/net/e*/device/virtfn*
```

in my python script using the subprocess library.

The output of this command is:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:52 /sys/class/net/enp1s0f0/device/virtfn0 -> ../0000:01:10.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:52 /sys/class/net/enp1s0f0/device/virtfn1 -> ../0000:01:10.2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:52 /sys/class/net/enp1s0f0/device/virtfn2 -> ../0000:01:10.4
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:52 /sys/class/net/enp1s0f0/device/virtfn3 -> ../0000:01:10.6
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:52 /sys/class/net/enp1s0f0/device/virtfn4 -> ../0000:01:11.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:52 /sys/class/net/enp1s0f0/device/virtfn5 -> ../0000:01:11.2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:52 /sys/class/net/enp1s0f0/device/virtfn6 -> ../0000:01:11.4
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:52 /sys/class/net/enp1s0f0/device/virtfn7 -> ../0000:01:11.6
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:52 /sys/class/net/enp1s0f1/device/virtfn0 -> ../0000:01:10.1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:52 /sys/class/net/enp1s0f1/device/virtfn1 -> ../0000:01:10.3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:52 /sys/class/net/enp1s0f1/device/virtfn2 -> ../0000:01:10.5
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:52 /sys/class/net/enp1s0f1/device/virtfn3 -> ../0000:01:10.7
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:52 /sys/class/net/enp1s0f1/device/virtfn4 -> ../0000:01:11.1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:52 /sys/class/net/enp1s0f1/device/virtfn5 -> ../0000:01:11.3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:52 /sys/class/net/enp1s0f1/device/virtfn6 -> ../0000:01:11.5
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:52 /sys/class/net/enp1s0f1/device/virtfn7 -> ../0000:01:11.7
```

The code in my script:

```
def getMacOfBusSlotFunction(self, slotbus, slotslot, slotfunction):
   myParentDevicesProcess = subprocess.Popen(['ls','-l','/sys/class/net/e*/device/virtfn*'])

    stdout , stderr = myParentDevicesProcess.communicate()
    print(stdout.decode("utf-8"))
```

I used [Retrieving the output of subprocess.call()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996518/retrieving-the-output-of-subprocess-call) as a basis.

I added the `.decode("utf-8")` part as I thought maybe the output was being returned as `bytes`. Including it and excluding it still give the same result...

The actual output I get from running this is a blank line (`\n`).

I expect the output to be the actual output of the command.

Comment: use this link `https://stackoverflow.com/a/75175057/12780274`  is very simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to tell `Popen` to capture the output/stderr; by default it just lets it go to the terminal. To fix, you just need to tell it to capture them via pipes to the parent process:

```
myParentDevicesProcess = subprocess.Popen(['ls','-l','/sys/class/net/e*/device/virtfn*'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Of course, that still won't work because glob expansion is a property of the shell, not the `ls` command, and you're not running your command through a shell (nor should you). You could have Python do the glob expansion for you to roughly match the shell with (putting `import glob` at the top of the file):

```
myParentDevicesProcess = subprocess.Popen(['ls','-l'] + glob.glob('/sys/class/net/e*/device/virtfn*'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Popen` (or any `subprocess` call), without `shell=True`, cannot use shell features like wildcard expansion.  If you had examined standard error too, you would have discovered an error message that `ls` could not find a file named literally `/sys/class/net/e*/device/virtfn`.

The trivial fix is to use a shell (and probably switch back to avoid bare `Popen`).

```py
listing = subprocess.check_output('ls -l /sys/class/net/e*/device/virtfn', shell=True)
```

In some ways, a better solution would be to use Python's native functions to extract the information you need, rather than [attempt to parse `ls` output](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) but since we don't know what information you want, that's a bit hard to pin down.  If your ultimate goal is to resolve the symlinks, try

```py
import glob
import os

for symlink in glob.glob('/sys/class/net/e*/device/virtfn'):
    print(os.readlink(symlink))
```