# start python script from another python script and show in console

Tags: python, console

I wanted to ask if it´s possible to display the progress of a python script that I started from another script in my console. I've googled quite a bit, but I can't find a command like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, it is called either a thread or a subprocess, depending on what you need.

In case of threading, the stdout will be shared between your main and other threads, so it simply works.

For a subprocess, you will have to either use shell capabilities, or set the subprocess' output to be the parent process' stdout.
See for example this question : [Python subprocess output to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062340/python-subprocess-output-to-stdout)