# Does select() behave differently on python2 and python3?

Tags: linux, select, python-3.x, pipe, python-2.x

I want to read `stdout` and `stderr` from a subprocess in the same thread as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270645/can-you-make-a-python-subprocess-output-stdout-and-stderr-as-usual-but-also-cap/12272262#12272262) post. While running the code inside Python2.7 works as expected, the `select()` call in Python3.3 seems to do not what it should.

Have a look - here is a script that would print two lines on both `stdout` and `stderr`, then wait and then repeat this a couple of times:

```
import time, sys
for i in range(5):
    sys.stdout.write("std: %d\n" % i)
    sys.stdout.write("std: %d\n" % i)
    sys.stderr.write("err: %d\n" % i)
    sys.stderr.write("err: %d\n" % i)
    time.sleep(2)
```

The problematic script will start the script above in a subprocess and read it's `stdout` and `stderr` as described in the posted link:

```
import subprocess
import select

p = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/env', 'python', '-u', 'test-output.py'],
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

r = [p.stdout.fileno(), p.stderr.fileno()]

while p.poll() is None:
    print("select")
    ret = select.select(r, [], [])

    for fd in ret[0]:
        if fd == p.stdout.fileno():
            print("readline std")
            print("stdout: " + p.stdout.readline().decode().strip())
        if fd == p.stderr.fileno():
            print("readline err")
            print("stderr: " + p.stderr.readline().decode().strip())
```

Note that I start the Python subprocess using the `-u` option which causes Python to not buffer `stdout` and `stderr`. Also I print some text before calling `select()` and `readline()` to see, where the script blocks.

**And here is the problem:** running the script in Python3, after each cycle the output blocks for 2 seconds despite the fact, that two more lines are waiting to be read. And as indicated by the text before each call of `select()` you can see that it's `select()` which is blocking (not `readline()`).

My first thought was that `select()` only resumes on a flush on Python3 while Python2 it returns always when there's data available but in this case only one line would be read each 2 seconds (which is not the case!)

**So my question is:** is this a bug in Python3-select()? Did I misunderstand the behavior of `select()`? And is there a way to workaround this behavior without having to start a thread for each pipe?

Output when running Python3:

```
select
readline std
stdout: std: 0
readline err
stderr: err: 0
select            <--- here the script blocks for 2 seconds
readline std
stdout: std: 0
select
readline std
stdout: std: 1
readline err
stderr: err: 0
select            <--- here the script should block (but doesn't)
readline err
stderr: err: 1
select            <--- here the script blocks for 2 seconds
readline std
stdout: std: 1
readline err
stderr: err: 1
select            <--- here the script should block (but doesn't)
readline std
stdout: std: 2
readline err
stderr: err: 2
select
.
.
```

**Edit:** Please note that it has no influence whether the child process is a Python script. The following C++ program has the same effect:

```
int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        std::cout << "out: " << i << std::endl;
        std::cout << "out: " << i << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "err: " << i << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "err: " << i << std::endl;
        fflush(stdout);
        fflush(stderr);
        usleep(2000000);
}}
```

Comment: have you tried obvious things: call `.flush()` explicitly (`-u` behaves differently in Python 3 -- the streams are line-buffered); set `bufsize=0`; use `os.read(fd, 512)` instead of `.readline()`? The code itself is broken e.g.: there could be data buffered even if `p.poll() is not None`

Comment: Another change is that sys.stdout/err became io.TextIOWrapper objects in 3.x, with consistent behavior (and defaults) across platforms.  Before, for CPython, they were file objects that thinly wrapped the stdio structures of the particular C compiler used.  I suggest carefully reading the io module docs.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: the child process doesn't have to be a Python program. A C++ program which does the same (and flushes explicitly) will show the same effect. Also the `.poll()` has no influence - you can replace the line with `while True`. Currently I'm pretty convinced that `select()` is broken in Python3.

Comment: @frans: details matter. What happens if you use `os.read(fd, 512)` as I've suggested?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: you were right with the `bufsize=0` hint (and with `read()`, too) I didn't check it again because I did that already, but I think I had another issue at that time. Unfortunately I can't mark this as answer but your comments are worth the upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the reason is buffering in `subprocess.PIPE` and first `readline()` call reads all available data (i.e., two lines) and returns first one.

After that, there is no unread data in pipe, so `select()` is not returning immediately. You can check this by doubling readline calls:

```
print("stdout: " + p.stdout.readline().decode().strip())
print("stdout: " + p.stdout.readline().decode().strip())
```

and ensuring that second `readline()` call doesn't block.

One solution is to disable buffering using `bufsize=0`:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/env', 'python', '-u', 'test-output.py'],
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0)
```

Another possible solution is to do a non-blocking `readline()` or to ask pipe file object its read buffer size, but I don't know is it possible.

You can also read directly from `p.stdout.fileno()` to implement non-blocking `readline()`.

**Update:** Python2 vs. Python3

The reason why Python3 differs from Python2 here is likely to be in new I/O module ([PEP 31136](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3116/)). See this note:

> The BufferedIOBase methods signatures are mostly identical to that of RawIOBase (exceptions: write() returns None , read() 's argument is optional), but may have different semantics. In particular, BufferedIOBase implementations may read more data than requested or delay writing data using buffers.

Comment: It looks like you're right, setting `bufsize` to 0 (as J.F. Sebastian also suggested) does the trick . But I still don't see why the Python 2 behavior is different. Isn't the Python2 `read()` buffered, too?

Comment: @frans, it seems that in Python2, readline() reads only one line and returns it, while in Python3 it reads all available data and returns first line. I have updated the answer.