# Python - How to write in both files and console at the same time (from a Bash files)

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

```
with open('WarningErr.txt', 'w') as err:
    subprocess.call(cmd, stderr=err)

with open('WarningOut.txt', 'w') as out:
    return_code = subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=out)
```

Right now, I write both errors and output in ".txt and stdout".

But it is too slow. I write in one, and then in another.
I got to be able to write in both at the same time.

To replicate a little bit what the tee behaviour in Bash.

Comment: What don't you include `tee` in the command you call through `subprocess`?

Comment: This may be useful to you: [Can you make a python subprocess output stdout and stderr as usual, but also capture the output as a string? \[duplicate\]](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12270645/953482)

Comment: Thanks, but it worked very well with the subprocess call @Rightleg

Answer (score 0):

I included tee in the command call like @Rightleg suggested. I change the command. But now it works perfectly.

I didn't think that I could call tee via the subprocess. But it works real well!

```
 # for example
 command = 'ls'

 # To write at the same time in the shell and a file both errors, and stdout (TEE behaviour)
 cmd = ['bash', '-c', '. myBash.bash; {} > >(tee {}/WarningOut.txt) 2> >(tee {}/WarningErr.txt >&2)'
       .format(command, PATHTOWHEREYOUWANTIT_g, PATHTOWHEREYOUWANTIT_g)]

return_code = subprocess.call(cmd)
```

Comment: Could you please add your final code so it can be helpful to other users? :)

Answer (score 0):

guess you like to log to stdout/stderr and a file. Try the logging lib and this code:

```
import logging

# create logger obj
_glogger = logging.getLogger("myApp")

# create file sink
hdlr = logging.FileHandler(os.path.join("dumpDir",'myApp.log'))
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)s[%(process)d] %(levelname)s %(message)s')
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
_glogger.addHandler(hdlr)

# create steam sink = stdout
hdlr2 = logging.StreamHandler()
hdlr2.setFormatter(formatter)
_glogger.addHandler(hdlr2)
_glogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

_glogger.debug("a debug message")
```

Comment: Yes that is something that I will have to try eventually.