# Able to get stdout/stderr in realtime (in python) from sh script but not python script.

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I've encountered a weird behavior. I have a simple function to execute a command (with shell=True) and capture the output while printing it to the screen in realtime (curtsy of [Can you make a python subprocess output stdout and stderr as usual, but also capture the output as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270645/can-you-make-a-python-subprocess-output-stdout-and-stderr-as-usual-but-also-cap/12272262)).

I made two dummy scripts to test this. The first uses pure shell script (/bin/sh) to write some lines to both stdout and stderr. The second uses the shell script to invoke python to do the same process.

In the first case (sh) I capture all output as expected, but in the second case (python) all stderr is captured first and only then **some** of stdout is captured, but not all of it. What is going on here?

Here is my script

```
import subprocess
import sys
import select

def tee_command(sh_script):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(sh_script,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                            shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
    def getfd(s):
        # import six
        # if six.PY3:
        #     return s.buffer
        # else:
        return s.fileno()
    stdout = []
    stderr = []
    while True:
        reads = [getfd(proc.stdout), getfd(proc.stderr)]
        ret = select.select(reads, [], [])

        for fd in ret[0]:
            if fd == getfd(proc.stdout):
                read = proc.stdout.readline()
                sys.stdout.write('stdout: ' + str(read))
                sys.stdout.flush()
                stdout.append(read)
            if fd == getfd(proc.stderr):
                read = proc.stderr.readline()
                sys.stdout.write('stderr: ' + str(read))
                sys.stdout.flush()
                stderr.append(read)

        if proc.poll() is not None:
            break

    print('stdout:\n', ''.join(stdout))
    print('stderr:\n', ''.join(stderr))

from textwrap import dedent

sh_script = dedent(
    r'''
    for i in `seq 1 50`;
    do
        sleep .1
        >&1 echo "O$i"
        if [ "$(($i % 5))" = "0" ]; then
            >&2 echo "E$i"
        fi
    done
    ''').lstrip()
tee_command(sh_script)

sh_script = dedent(
    r'''
    python -c "
    import sys
    import time
    for i in range(100):
        time.sleep(.1)
        sys.stdout.write('O{}\n'.format(i))
        if i % 5 == 0:
            sys.stderr.write('E{}\n'.format(i))
    "
    ''').lstrip()
tee_command(sh_script)
```

The first case produces

```
stdout: O1
stdout: O2
stdout: O3
stdout: O4
stdout: O5
stderr: E5
stdout: O6
stdout: O7
stdout: O8
stdout: O9
stdout: O10
stderr: E10
stdout: O11
stdout: O12
stdout: O13
stdout: O14
stdout: O15
stderr: E15
stdout: O16
stdout: O17
stdout: O18
stdout: O19
stdout: O20
stderr: E20
stdout: O21
stdout: O22
stdout: O23
stdout: O24
stdout: O25
stderr: E25
stdout: O26
stdout: O27
stdout: O28
stdout: O29
stdout: O30
stderr: E30
stdout: O31
stdout: O32
stdout: O33
stdout: O34
stdout: O35
stderr: E35
stdout: O36
stdout: O37
stdout: O38
stdout: O39
stdout: O40
stderr: E40
stdout: O41
stdout: O42
stdout: O43
stdout: O44
stdout: O45
stderr: E45
stdout: O46
stdout: O47
stdout: O48
stdout: O49
stdout: O50
stderr: E50
stdout: stderr: stdout:
 O1
O2
O3
O4
O5
O6
O7
O8
O9
O10
O11
O12
O13
O14
O15
O16
O17
O18
O19
O20
O21
O22
O23
O24
O25
O26
O27
O28
O29
O30
O31
O32
O33
O34
O35
O36
O37
O38
O39
O40
O41
O42
O43
O44
O45
O46
O47
O48
O49
O50

stderr:
 E5
E10
E15
E20
E25
E30
E35
E40
E45
E50
```

But the second case writes:

```
stderr: E0
stderr: E5
stderr: E10
stderr: E15
stderr: E20
stderr: E25
stderr: E30
stderr: E35
stderr: E40
stderr: E45
stderr: E50
stderr: E55
stderr: E60
stderr: E65
stderr: E70
stderr: E75
stderr: E80
stderr: E85
stderr: E90
stderr: E95
stdout: O0
stdout: O1
stdout: O2
stdout: O3
stdout: O4
stdout: O5
stdout: O6
stdout: O7
stdout: O8
stdout: O9
stdout: O10
stdout: O11
stdout: O12
stdout: O13
stdout: O14
stdout: O15
stdout: O16
stdout: O17
stdout: O18
stdout: O19
stdout: O20
stdout: O21
stdout: O22
stdout: O23
stdout: O24
stdout: O25
stdout: O26
stdout: O27
stdout: O28
stdout: O29
stdout: O30
stdout: O31
stdout: O32
stdout: O33
stdout: O34
stdout: O35
stdout: O36
stdout: O37
stdout: O38
stderr: stdout:
 O0
O1
O2
O3
O4
O5
O6
O7
O8
O9
O10
O11
O12
O13
O14
O15
O16
O17
O18
O19
O20
O21
O22
O23
O24
O25
O26
O27
O28
O29
O30
O31
O32
O33
O34
O35
O36
O37
O38

stderr:
 E0
E5
E10
E15
E20
E25
E30
E35
E40
E45
E50
E55
E60
E65
E70
E75
E80
E85
E90
E95
```

I'm running Python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the bash standard output is line buffered whereas python has fixed length buffer. If you change add a `flush` call to the python script:

```
for i in range(100):
    time.sleep(.1)
    sys.stdout.write('O{}\n'.format(i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    if i % 5 == 0:
        sys.stderr.write('E{}\n'.format(i))
"
''').lstrip()
```

then you will see the same expected result for both inner scripts.

Python does line buffering for stderr so the stderr is always printed out.

When the inner python script terminates the complete stdout buffer is flushed but the method `tee_command` reads the data from process stdout line by line. So it reads perhaps one line and then `if proc.poll()` detects the child process exited and the rest of lines are ignored.

Comment: Perfect. Adding the flush and checking for lines after `proc.poll() is not None` works like a charm. Thank you. Is there anyway to control how an executed program does buffering or is that completely up to the program?

Comment: The program controls its buffering. How to affect python program buffering see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering.