# Run external command from Python. Then display the output on screen and get the output simultaneously

Tags: python, subprocess

I know that it is easy to run an external command from Python and display the output on the screen. For example: (It will display the output **only on the screen**)

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['dir'])
```

I also know that we can run an external command from Python and get the output. For example: (It will **store the output** as a string in variable *out* and will **not display** the output on the screen anymore)

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.Popen(['dir'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = result.stdout.read()
```

My question is: Is there a way to display the output on the screen and store and output in a variable **simultaneously**? In other words, when I run the code, the external command output will display on the screen. At the same time, a variable in the code can get the output displayed on the screen.

Update: I found out if I include `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` in `subprocess.Popen`, it will display nothing on the screen (windows command prompt).

Related questions:

[live output from subprocess command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421757/live-output-from-subprocess-command?rq=1)

[Output of subprocess both to PIPE and directly to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558074/output-of-subprocess-both-to-pipe-and-directly-to-stdout?rq=1)

Comment: Why not just print the `out`? Am I missing something?

Comment: That works. But the terminal window will open twice. The terminal window will display nothing if I store the output in `out` and the terminal window will open again to print the `out`. Note, I am executing the code in a Python script not in a command window.

Comment: Does `ls | tee` work?

Comment: Actually, I am testing in windows platform. `ls` is just for demonstration.

Comment: I found `| tee` works. The solution for windows platform is to use powershell and `| tee`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `| tee` (On windows platform, use Powershell):

```
import subprocess

# Run command in powershell and redirect it by | tee to a file named out.txt 
result = subprocess.Popen(['powershell', command, '|', 'tee', 'out.txt'])

# Get standard output
f = open('out.txt')
out = f.read()
f.close()
```

By this way, the screen will display the output on PowerShell terminal and the output will also be stored in *out*.

Answer (score 1):

If you need real-time output from `Popen` , you could use something like this (*Windows* platform according to your [last comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46081729/run-external-command-from-python-then-display-the-output-on-screen-and-get-the#comment79127743_46081729)):

**Byte stream**:

```
import sys, subprocess
out=b''
result = subprocess.Popen(['cmd', '/c', 'dir /B 1*.txt'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
    universal_newlines=False)
for s_line in result.stdout:
    #Parse it the way you want
    out += s_line
    print( s_line.decode(sys.stdout.encoding).replace('\r\n',''))

# debugging output
print(out.decode(sys.stdout.encoding))
```

**Text stream**:

```
import subprocess
out=''
result = subprocess.Popen(['cmd', '/c', 'dir /B 1*.txt'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
    universal_newlines=True)
for s_line in result.stdout:
    #Parse it the way you want
    out += s_line
    print( s_line.rstrip())

# debugging output
print(out)
```

The latter code snippet **output**:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> out=''
>>> result = subprocess.Popen(['cmd', '/c', 'dir /B 1*.txt'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
...     universal_newlines=True)
>>> for s_line in result.stdout:
...     #Parse it the way you want
...     out += s_line
...     print( s_line.rstrip())
...
1.325.txt
1049363a.txt
1049363b.txt
1051416.txt
1207235log.txt
>>> print(out)
1.325.txt
1049363a.txt
1049363b.txt
1051416.txt
1207235log.txt

>>>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I still get nothing in the windows command prompt. If I include `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` in `subprocess.Popen`, it will always redirect and display nothing on the screen.