# Subprocess: not output

Tags: java, python, subprocess, ipc, stdout

I'm using the subprocess module to start a subprocess (java program) and connect to it's output stream (stdout). But when i try to get its stdout there is no output.

```
p= subprocess.Popen(["java -Xmx256m -jar bin/HelloWorld.jar"],cwd=r'/home/karen/sphinx4-1.0beta5-src/sphinx4-1.0beta5/', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize= 4024)

        out, err = p.communicate()
        print out
```

I want to be able to execute non-blocking reads on its stdout too.
How can i do both things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split up the first arg into a list of your args; I think the reason you're getting no output is that your shell is looking to execute a file named "java -Xmx256m -jar bin/HelloWorld.jar" which clearly isn't going to exist.  You want `["java", "-Xmx256m", "-jar", "bin/HelloWorld.jar"]` as the first arg instead, like:

```
cmd = ["java", "-Xmx256m", "-jar", "bin/HelloWorld.jar"]
cwd = r'/home/karen/sphinx4-1.0beta5-src/sphinx4-1.0beta5/'
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, cwd=cwd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=4024 )

out, err = p.communicate()
print out
```

Re: wanting to execute non-blocking reads on stdout, see this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585692/python-nonblocking-subprocess-check-stdout).

Comment: `"java -Xmx256m -jar bin/HelloWorld.jar"` is the command that i want my shell runs... when i execute it on my shell it runs sucessfully!

Comment: I understand - but that's a full command string, not a *filename* which is what your command is trying to execute.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, with a HelloWorld that just does `System.out.println("Hello World!");`

```
import subprocess

p= subprocess.Popen(["java","-jar","HelloWorld.jar"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize= 4024)

out, err = p.communicate()
print out
```

This answer already covers reading non-blocking from a subprocess:  [python: nonblocking subprocess, check stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585692/python-nonblocking-subprocess-check-stdout)